# Basic, community-endorsed autocorrect

Tags: feature-request, spelling, automatic-edits

In an answer to [what SO is not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not), we seem to be in agreement that it is [not a spell-checker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128558/135216). However, we also know that it does *use* a spell-checker.

Would it make sense to have a community-endorsed spell-checker or auto-correct functionality? For example, a post that uses the term, *outlook*, might be improved by a contextual autocorrect that suggests (or actually replaces that with) *Outlook* if the post was tagged **Microsoft**.

I recognize a community-voted, contextual checker is non-trivial, but it seems useful or at least interesting, and may provide some real value in improving the quality of the content -- one of the missions of the SE sites in general. Perhaps a particular suggestion only becomes reality if some threshold is met. In this way, we humans can concentrate on edits focused on intent and content rather than syntax and spelling.

Comment: As long as when I write colour it doesn't auto-correct to color, I'd be happy for this.

Comment: True enough. It would need to be localized to the subject matter more so than language nuances...